# How to write String to txt file and send it to server

Tags: java, android, string, file

I want to develop an application in android in which I need to capture image and convert that image to string and write that string in txt file and send it to server where server reads that file and convert that string to image again...

now i have done with image taking part and converting that image into string and writing that string to txt file.

but when am try to read that file and convert that string into the image it's not working...

Code for converting image into string is

```
File imageFile = new File(path);
Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(imageFile.getAbsolutePath());
ByteArrayOutputStream stream = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
bitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.PNG, 90, stream);
byte[] image = stream.toByteArray();
imgstr = Base64.encodeToString(image, 0);
```

Code for writing that into file is

```
File file = new File("new.txt");
FileWriter w = new FileWriter("/sdcard/new/new.txt");
BufferedWriter out = new BufferedWriter(w);
out.write(data);
out.flush();
out.close();
```

And code for read that file and convert that string to image again is

```
FileInputStream fstream = new FileInputStream("/sdcard/new/new.txt");          
DataInputStream in = new DataInputStream(fstream);
BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(in));
String strLine;
ArrayList list=new ArrayList();
while ((strLine = br.readLine()) != null)
{
    list.add(strLine);
}
Iterator itr;
for (itr=list.iterator(); itr.hasNext(); )
{
    String str=itr.next().toString(); 
    StringBuffer sb=new StringBuffer(str);
    int length=sb.length();
    String imageDataString = sb.substring(0, length);
    byte[] decodedString = Base64.decode(imageDataString, Base64.DEFAULT);
    Bitmap decodedByte = BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(decodedString, 0,decodedString.length); 
    FileOutputStream imageOutFile = new FileOutputStream("/sdcard/new/android.jpg");
    imageOutFile.write(decodedString);
    imageOutFile.close();
    System.out.println("File converted");
```

but its not converting that string into image
please tell me solution for it...

Comment: Try to ouput String that you get after `Base64.encode` and stirng taht you are passing to `Base64.decode` to compare them. If they too long to compare - output they hash values and check if they equal.

Comment: @yograjshinde exactly why do you want to convert an image to a string to send it?  is this some kind of homebaked cryptography? the string's only advantage is content / format manipulation, but this is definitely NOT the way to manipulate images.  why not just upload the images directly?  PLUS, image data converted to string will probably occupy MORE space.  please satisfy my curiosity, because you certainly have a reason to be doing this.

Comment: Why image -> String -> image? Just send it as byte array.

Comment: @Nikita Beloglazow hi thanx for the reply i have checked it its showing its not equal... can u have any suggestion for it?

Comment: @tony gil i have tried that solution also but its taking too much time for sending approxly 30 min for 100 kb image file.

Comment: @YograjShinde if that is the problem you are getting then there is a bigger problem elsewhere. Fix the original problem rather than hack around it.

Comment: @YograjShinde IF you edit your question, i can certainly propose a solution for uploading images to remote server on the web.

Comment: Please don't use DataInputStream to read text and don't use StringBuffer when you can use StringBuilder http://vanillajava.blogspot.co.uk/2012/08/java-memes-which-refuse-to-die.html

Answer (score 0):

if all you need is uploading files via ftp from android to web server, this will do the trick (working from froyo up - BUT you must import [apache commons](http://commons.apache.org/net/download_net.cgi) and install a copy inside your "src" folder):

```
import java.io.FileInputStream;
import org.apache.commons.net.ftp.FTPClient;
import android.util.Log;
public class FtpFileUp implements Runnable {

    private final String TAG = "FTPfile";
    boolean flagFTPOK = false;

    String fileName, fileDirSubLocalName, fileDirSubRemoteName;
    String fileDirName = NavigationActivity.fileDirName;


    FtpFileUp (String fileNameIn, String fileDirSubLocalNameIn, String fileDirSubRemoteNameIn) {
        fileName = (String) fileNameIn;
        fileDirSubLocalName = (String) fileDirSubLocalNameIn;
        fileDirSubRemoteName = (String) fileDirSubRemoteNameIn;
    }
    FtpFileUp (String fileNameIn) {
        String fileDirSubNameIn = "";
        fileName = (String) fileNameIn;
        fileDirSubLocalName = (String) fileDirSubNameIn;
        fileDirSubRemoteName = (String) fileDirSubNameIn;
    }
    FtpFileUp (String fileNameIn, String fileDirSubNameIn) {
        fileName = (String) fileNameIn;
        fileDirSubLocalName = (String) fileDirSubNameIn;
        fileDirSubRemoteName = (String) fileDirSubNameIn;
    }

    @Override
    public void run() {
        String ftpConnectString = "ftp.yourdomain.com";
        if (fileDirSubRemoteName != "") fileDirSubRemoteName += "/";
        if (fileDirSubLocalName != "") fileDirSubLocalName += "/";
        FTPClient ftpCli = new FTPClient();
        try {
           FileInputStream fis = new FileInputStream(fileDirName+"/"+fileDirSubLocalName+fileName);
           ftpCli.connect(ftpConnectString);
           ftpCli.login("user", "password");
           Log.i(TAG, "ok ftp "+ftpCli.getDataConnectionMode());
           ftpCli.storeFile("/"+fileDirSubRemoteName+fileName, fis);
           fis.close();
           flagFTPOK = true;
        } catch (Exception except) {
           Log.i(TAG, "ftp up FAIL "+except);
        }
    }

}
```

which you would call using the following code (encapsulated by TRY CATCH)

```
Thread ftpThread01 = new Thread(new FtpFileUp("fileName", "", "/www/android/imgUpload"));
ftpThread01.start();
```

NOTE: as you can see, there are 2 alternative constructors that you may use to automatize your ftp, by storing default locations.  they may be removed with no harm.